# Repeated warning trace from javax.mail after updating

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I recently went forward and updated our codebase's JavaMail API to the latest one.

All in all the process was very smooth and I did not encounter any problem. Thing is though that now my app keeps displaying the following warning message:

```
Jun 04, 2019 10:32:02 AM javax.mail.Session loadResource 
WARNING: expected resource not found: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
```

My search online about this was twofold:

- Understand what is causing this problem
- Understand how to fix it

Both yielded no results. So my question is, does anyone know the answer to the above mentioned questions?

Comment: This file should be in resources of `javamail`. You didn't see this warning before, because it was in debug logs. All files from `resources` folder should be imported by default in Maven, did you somehow change the dependency declaration or you use something else?

Comment: I'm not using a dependency management system. It's a legacy project where everything is managed manually. I simply replaced our old jars with the new. A list of them is this javax.mail-api.jar
mailapi.jar
smtp.jar
imap.jar
pop3.jar
dsn.jar

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong jar files.  Get rid of all those JavaMail jar files and replace them with just the javax.mail.jar file, Maven coordinates com.sun.mail:javax.mail.

Comment: Is it considered "wrong" even though a scenario of where a project may only, for example, include mailapi and smtp, a scenario which appears to be [supported](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/NOTES.txt), will also have this warning?

Though I agree that in the OP's case, they included everything which is not necessary.

Comment: "Wrong" only applied to this case.  There are other use cases where using only some of the JavaMail jar files is correct, but for most people it's simpler to just ignore that.